# sql server Concatenate Multiple Rows Using FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the XML PATH method of concatenating multiple rows. So, given the following sql-table, temptable

```
user | userid | email    |   group

a      usera    a@a.com     admin
a      usera    a@a.com     test
a      usera    a@a.com     edit
b      userb    b@a.com     read
b      userb    b@a.com     write
c      userc    c@c.com     read
c      userc    c@c.com     write
```

i receive with this code the following:

```
SELECT a.[user],

STUFF((SELECT  ', ' +  [group] [text()]
      FROM [temptable] 
      WHERE [user] = a.[user]
      for XML PATH (''),TYPE).
      value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS [group]

FROM [temptable] as a
GROUP BY a.[user]
```

result:

```
user |   group

a      admin,test,edit
b      read,write
c      read,write
```

but i need this

```
    user | userid | email    |   group

    a      usera    a@a.com     admin,test,edit
    b      userb    b@a.com     read,write
    c      userc    c@c.com     read,write
```

Comment: just edited you sql script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT a.[user],a.userid,a.email
STUFF((SELECT  ', ' +  [group] [text()]
      FROM [temptable] b on a.[user]=b.[user]
      for XML PATH (''),TYPE).
      value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS [group]
FROM [temptable] as a
GROUP BY a.[user],a.userid,a.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include other column also in `group by` clause :

```
SELECT a.[user], userid, email,
       STUFF((SELECT  ', ' +  [group] [text()]
              FROM [temptable] 
              WHERE [user] = a.[user]
              FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,''
            ) AS [group]
FROM [temptable] AS a
GROUP BY a.[user], userid, email;
```

However, `DISTINCT` would also solve your problem :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[user], userid, email,
           STUFF((SELECT  ', ' +  [group] [text()]
                  FROM [temptable] 
                  WHERE [user] = a.[user]
                  FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,''
                ) AS [group]
FROM [temptable] AS a;
```